# Can I tell certbot to send an email on successful renewal

Tags: certbot

I was setting up a post-hook script to reload my ngnix on ubuntu when certbot got a new certificate. By now this works fine, but is there a way to get an email on a **successful renewal** from letsencrypt? I mean, I get them if it failed, but it would be nice to get one if it's successful too.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Bernhard

Comment: There's [this hook](https://github.com/hstock/certbot-renew-email) that could be used. However it won't include logs from other hooks. Did you happen to find some solution to get the printout from hooks?